# Alter Table Set Statistics requires table lock

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have run into a case such that Pg always preferring into a sequential scan for a table that has around 70M rows. (Index scan is ideal for that query and i have confirmed it by setting enable_seq_scan=off, speed improved by 200x)

So, in order to help Pg understand my data better i executed this

`ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname SET STATISTICS 1000;`

Unfortunately this requires [Update Exclusive lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertable.html) which locks the entire table (too much lock).

1. Is there a solution to avoid locking for this statement ?
2. Data sharding is done for this table based on Primary Key Range, so I would like Pg to even understand my Pk better so that it knows which User has got large data. Will it be of use if i increase the statistics of PrimaryKey column as well ?

Comment: It's a **share** update exclusive lock which only prevents DDL on the table, but not DML. Do you really need to run concurrent DDL statements in the very short time that setting the stats property takes?

Comment: To be precise: that "very short time" is in the range of a few milliseconds. I tried this on a table with 50 million rows and it took about 5ms. If you can't find a window of 5 milliseconds where you can't run a DDL statement there is something wrong with your application design (that the statement is **not** blocked by any running DML statement/transaction nor does it block a DML statement)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name replied in the comments of Evan's answer. If you have any idea about my 2nd question related to data sharding.. please do share your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

From the very docs you linked

> **SET STATISTICS**
>
> This form sets the per-column statistics-gathering target for subsequent ANALYZE operations. The target can be set in the range 0 to 10000; alternatively, set it to -1 to revert to using the system default statistics target (default_statistics_target). For more information on the use of statistics by the PostgreSQL query planner, refer to Section 14.2.
>
> SET STATISTICS acquires a **SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE lock.**

And, on the [docs for Explicit Locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html)

> **SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE**
>   Conflicts with the SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE, SHARE, SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE, EXCLUSIVE, and ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock modes. This mode protects a table against concurrent schema changes and VACUUM runs.
>
> Acquired by VACUUM (without FULL), ANALYZE, CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY, and ALTER TABLE VALIDATE and other ALTER TABLE variants (for full details see ALTER TABLE).

So you can't change the schema, or vacuum while analytics are happening. So what? They should happen very fast. Almost instantly.

Comment: I don't understand the reference to `count(*)` - isn't `set statistics` pretty much instantaneous?

Comment: No, afaik it does a single table scan, but I could be off on that.

Comment: No it doesn't do a full table scan.

Comment: Just tried this on a table with 50 million rows. The `alter table` took about 5ms. Clearly it does not do a table scan.

Comment: Depends also on your setting of `default_statistics_target` - default is 100 entries. If you have higher setting recalculation of statistics takes longer.

Comment: horse and evan, you guys are right, then i am left with no clue as to why all the DML of table started hanging around soon after i executed that statement! Apart from that am quite confident of that statement had taken a time of more than 40s+ to execute in my production DB, i aborted the execution in 40ish and all other operations of table started functioning normally. Is it possible for vacuum to have played any role there ? apart from stalling the execution of this alter query is there any explanation for my DML having got affected ?

Comment: No idea from that description, sounds like a deadlock, but without as select on `pg_locks` during the problem I can't diagnose it.

Comment: thanks for trying, but i did check for deadlock trace in pg log.. it was not found.. Anyways, with regard to my 2nd question relating to Data Sharding, any idea ?

Comment: Can you get that [app-level data from this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html)? I would think not.